# Macro To Scroll Through Tools in Adobe Illustrator CS5.1

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm just beginning to use Illustrator and am pretty well versed in Photoshop. In Photoshop, you can hit Shift + (the macro for the tool) and it'll scroll through the subtools. For example, you can hold Shift and hit E a couple times and it will scroll through the Eraser tools.

This doesn't work the same in Illustrator and I can't seem to find the macro on Google. Anybody know how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: This behavior isn't true for all tool groups.  While Shift+E will cycle through all Erasers, Shift+M will only cycle through 2 of the 4 Marquee tools.

Comment: True. I guess I was just seeing if there was anything like this for Illustrator. It appears there is not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fundamental difference between the way Ps handles tool selection vs. Ai. In Ps the same shortcut key can apply to multiple tools, and when this is the case you can cycle through them with Shift+[key] (or just [key] if you deselect `Use Shift key for Tool Switch` in Preferences).

In Ai this isn't possible. M is assigned to the Rectangle tool, and you can't *also* assign it to the Rounded Rectangle tool. Each tool is selected with its own keyboard shortcut, or the mouse.